# How can I customize the style of a checkbox which is in indeterminate state?

Tags: css, reactjs, checkbox

So I'm trying to customize my checkbox so that it will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEk99.jpg) in indeterminate state. The checked and unchecked work fine, but I can't make the indeterminate one show up properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
 I have tried `tag.class:indeterminate {}` and `input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate {}` in the style sheet but it doesn't seem to work.

My code and CSS sample: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fse6oo?file=style.css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do the similar approach on `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements for the `:indeterminate` state, just like you did with `:checked` state.

Remove this part from CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    color: white;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    background-color:#3B99FC;
}
```

Add these to CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    color: white;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    background-color:#3B99FC;
}
input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 2px 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

You can adjust the size/position of the indeterminate state minus-sign inside `input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate::after` style.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I didn't know that indeterminate should have before and after too.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to completely remove the minus-sign?